# Doubleclick ad unit I created is not showing image just target link

Tags: wordpress, double-click-advertising

I created an ad unit in my doubleclick with a created and created a tag and placed it in a text widget on my wordpress site but only thing that shows is the target link and not the image why?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out:

https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1739296?hl=en

Maybe it could help